# groupby keeping all previous fields

Tags: python, pandas

I have duplicate entries that I need to combine. All fields are the same except for two fields called `id1` and `id2` -- these are list fields and I want to combine their entries. Here is how I would do that for only the `id1` and `id2` fields:

```
summary_df = df.groupby(['path_md5']).agg(
    id1 =('id1', lambda x: str(sorted({id for ids in x.dropna() for id in ids}))),
    id2 =('id2', lambda x: str(sorted({id for ids in x.dropna() for id in ids}))),
)
```

Yet, I don't want to add in 60 additional fields that say `first` so that I can grab their value. Is there a better way to do this? Here is an example of input/output I want:

```
id1     id2     path_md5       other_fields (could be 50 fields -- all the same)...
[1,2]   [3]     abc            ...
[7]     [9]     abc            ...
[17]    [11]    xyz            ...
```

And the result should be:

```
id1        id2     path_md5       other_fields...
[1,2,7]   [3,9]     abc            ...
[17]      [11]      xyz            ...
```

What would be the best way to do this?

---

I tried doing the following:

```
# Dedupe path, combining id1, id2
agg_fields = [col_name for col_name in df.columns if col_name not in ('id1', 'id2')]
raw_df = raw_df.groupby(agg_fields).agg(...).reset_index()
```

But it was giving me zero results (maybe since a lot of the values are null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build an agg dictionary:

```
agg_dict = {k:'first' for k in df.columns if k not in ['id1','id2','path_md5']}
agg_dict['id1'] = lambda x: str(sorted({id for ids in x.dropna() for id in ids}))
agg_dict['id2'] = lambda x: str(sorted({id for ids in x.dropna() for id in ids}))

summary_df = df.groupby('path_md5', as_index=False).agg(agg_dict)
```

Comment: thanks, one question: why specify the `as_index=False` ? What does that do.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 that keeps `path_md5` as a normal column instead of the index of the groupby dataframe.

Comment: I see. How does that relate to doing `reset_index()` then afterwords, or are they unrelated?

Comment: Same effect, probably Pandas does the same thing behind the curtain.

Comment: ok cool. By the way, where can I learn more about that? I've looked at the `groupby page` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html but it just has a couple cryptic sentences and no examples.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 see [groupby.aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html?highlight=pandas%20core%20groupby%20dataframegroupby%20agg).